# Mass + velocity to pressure. How to measure pickleball flex without hurling it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, momentum, collision, projectile

I want to know how much a pickleball (it's like a whiffleball) compresses when it hits the floor.  I can't afford a 500,000 fps camera, so maybe an approach using basic principles would work. I also don't know much physics - only enough to think that this is possible.

The pickleball weighs 25 grams. It may strike the floor (let's say perpendicular to it) at  (let's say) 100 kph.

What I want to do is subject a fixed pickleball to pressure, using weight on it or some kind of a vise that measures pressure, and observe how much it flexes.

So my questions are

1. is my basic notion sound?
2. is my plan actionable without expensive equipment?
3. What are the calculations that I need to make?

Comment: Is measuring how much it deforms due to varying force all you need to determine? What will you do with this information (if you don't mind me asking)?

Comment: Yes. So glad you asked!  The ball is in bounds if it touches the boundary line.  That means actually touch - it does *not* mean that an imaginary vertical going up from the line would touch the ball.  Players often say that you should imagine a dime-sized area on the bottom of the ball as the contact area, though for a ball at rest it is much smaller.  I'm curious to know the actual size for the moving ball. It's largely curiosity, but I suppose that if I could show that compression is insignificant, we could start saying that if the *center* of the ball is over the line, it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notion is sound.  The key is that, to stop the downward motion of the ball, it must convert all of the kinetic energy of the ball into potential energy.  This means we can use the formula for work, $W=Fd$.  Work is force times distance.

One concern might be that the slow compression of the ball will not yield the same behavior as an impact.  And this is true to some degree.  A fast moving impact will not be in quite the same level of equilibrium.  But youre not talking speed of sound like impacts, so you can probably ignore that.

You will need to measure both the force the ball applies on the vice and the distance it compressed.  The two together show how much energy has been stored.

Take several measurements on the way.  The force the ball applies likely changes as it is compressed.  Lots of small changes will get you closer to the answer.  (Look into calculus for the reasons why)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.  I'm still looking for something more specific.  If I use a vise, what kind of a vise would measure the force. In what units?  Could I use weight instead of a vise?  What units would be used to state the force of the ball as it hits the ground?

Comment: If you used a vice, you would want a load cell in the vice to measure the force.  But all that really matters is that you can measure force and distance at the same time.  Weights would work just fine as long as you make sure all of the force goes through the balls (or at least it is a predictable force).  Due to how affordable the setup would be, my first attempt would be to put three balls in a triangle under a board and add weights in the center of the board, measuring the height of the ball every step of the way.  But I am not familiar with a pickleball, so that approach may
...

Comment: ... need to be adjusted to work with the particular behaviors of the balls.  As for units, a force is a force, so the force of the ball striking the ground would be measured in Newtons.  Just remember that the force will increase as the ball compresses.  The simplest case would be if the force varies linearly with compression distance.  This would mean your ball acts like an ideal spring, and you can invoke Hooke's Law.  But your ball may behave differently from an ideal spring.